# What is the meaning of semi-handcrafted features?

Tags: machine-learning

I know handcrafted features are features which are being created by a human made algorithm. But what are semi-handcrafted features?

Comment: any reference to where you encountered the term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means part of it handled by the human at first, and then, base on them running a machinery learning algorithms to extract new features. For example, gather some features from the human about some pictures, and using some machinery algorithms to find some new features by some non-linear combinations of those features.

Comment: thanks for the quick comment. So an example would be (given a 2D image that I somehow convert that to an image that is rotation invariant (as the CNN does not have to find that feature anymore) and then feed that example to a CNN to find more features?  If I would directly feed that image into the CNN this would be called then "non-handcrafted' or 'learned' features? Or is there some other name?